# Matrix inverse exists even determinate is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

We know matrix inverse does not exist if det(matrix)=0.

Now a 2*2 matrix with all entries $x$ has inverse as 2*2 matrix all entries $1/(4*x)$ .

So what is the gap of understanding?

Comment: What you say is false. Have you tried to write down the matrices and multiplying them?

Comment: yea here identity is 2*2 matrix all entries 1/2.

Comment: Identity is the diagonal matrix ($1$ on the diagonal and $0$ everywhere else).

Comment: why? id means that makes no change on operation. please check my example with calculations.

Comment: WHY DOWNVOTE??????????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\x&x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{4x}&\frac{1}{4x}\\\frac{1}{4x}&\frac{1}{4x}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$, and this is not the identity matrix of the *full* matrix ring $M_2(F)$, which is $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.

However, $\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$ *is* the identity matrix of the ring of matrices of the form $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\x&x\end{bmatrix}\mid x\in F\right\}$.

The determinant-invertibility criterion does not hold for this subring. It is meant to work for the full matrix ring $M_2(F)$.

In the full matrix ring, you can easily see that $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\x&x\end{bmatrix}$ isn't invertible since it is a zero divisor: $\begin{bmatrix}x&x\\x&x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

If we were able to invert on the left, then we would wind up with $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, a contradiction.

Comment: WHY DOES NOT HOLD FOR SUBRING? WHAT IS THE DEEPER MATH BEHIND THIS?

Comment: @user123804 WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? Even my icon is covering its ears...

Comment: @user123804 Counterquestion: Why *should* it hold for a subring?!

Comment: CHECK YOUR CALCULATIONS. THERE IS A MISTEK...

Comment: @user123804 Doh, i erased the negative while copy and pasting. Fixed.

Comment: Simply put, there is no reason to expect that units of rings inside of bigger rings are still units in the bigger ring. This is a demonstration of that. This is true if they share their multiplicative identity, though.

Comment: But the set you construct is not a subring. It is a subset that fulfils the ring axioms. A subring has also to contain the multiplicative identity (which yours doesnt).

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just saw that there are two possible ways how people define subring: One with same multiplicative identity and one without. You implicitly assumed the latter.

Comment: @AndreasH. Yeah, I'm an oddball like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x\ne 0,$ we have $$\begin{bmatrix}x & x\\x & x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/(4x) & 1/(4x)\\1/(4x) & 1/(4x)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix},$$ but this is not the identity matrix, as (for an easy example) $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1/2 & 1/2\\1/2 & 1/2\end{bmatrix}\neq\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Your last line is wrong.

Comment: @Daniel: My thanks. Fixed.